# Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have just converted my project to androidx and am now getting the "Program type already present" error for `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture`.

I have looked through multiple stackoverflow solutions and some of the Gradle documentation and still can't get it to work.

The problem is that there are two versions of ListenableFuture brought in by Gradle in these modules:

```
Gradle: com.google.quava:quava:23.5jre@jar 
Gradle: com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0@jar
```

I would guess that I want to exclude the second one, but can not figure out how to do it.

You can see what I have tried in my gradle file, but no joy so far.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.drme.weathertest"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

//    added 1/2/19 to try and prevent java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
//    Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion "26.+"
                }
            }
        }
//        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.quava.listenablefuture:1.0',
//                'com.google.common.util.concurrent.listenablefuture'
    }

//    compile('com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0@jar') {
//        // causing "Program type already present" compile errors
//        //exclude("com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0")
//        exclude('com.google.guava:listenablefuture')
//        exclude('listenablefuture-1.0.jar')
//        //exclude("maven.com.google.quava.listenablefuture")
//    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/com.drme.weatherNoaa/Data', 'src/main/java/2']
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    // causing "Program type already present" compile errors // did not fix problem
    implementation('com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0') {
        exclude module: 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture'
    }
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha01'
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.1.0-alpha01"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha03"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha03'
}
```

If I am looking at the dependencies correctly, it looks like it comes from `androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha03`.

```
+--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha03@aar
+--- androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0-alpha02@jar
+--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0@jar
```

Suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the problem and the answer.  Looking at the External Libraries in the Project view I found the following:

```
Gradle: com.google.guava:guava:23.5-jre@jar 
 |_ guava-23.5-jre.jar 
    |_com.google
      |_common 
        |_util.concurrent
          |_ListenableFuture

Gradle: com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0@jar
 |_listenablefuture-1.0.jar
   |_com.google.common.util.concurrent
     |_ListenableFuture
```

The only thing in the second entry was the duplicate ListenableFuture.

By making the following entry in the gradle build file, this problem went away:

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion "26.+"
                }
            }
        }

        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture' <===This fixed the problem
    }
```

I could not figure out what was generating the `com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0@jar`, but the resulting problem was solved.

Thanks for all who reviewed the problem.

Comment: `Program type already present` means that there are duplicate classes... excluding all occurrences most likely has undesired side-effects; better keep one of them. `./gradlew app:dependencies` would list them. if my approach did not work, there might be more than two occurrences present.

Comment: Martin: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am only aware of the two `build.gradle` files in my Android Studio project and could not figure out how to run your suggestion to list the dependencies.  I looked at the gradle documentation and almost killed my project trying to add build scans. :)  Could you provide a link to show how to implement your suggestion in more detail?  I am not a command line guru.  Thanks.

Comment: it is giving error 
configuration ':app:annotationProcessor' after it has been included in dependency resolution.

Comment: This what I only had to include in my app's gradle file configurations.all {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}

Comment: Its work but got some issue: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture
`

Answer (score 3):

you cannot exclude `listenablefuture` from `listenablefuture`

... try something alike this instead:

```
implementation ("androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha03") {
    exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "listenablefuture"
}
```

Comment: Martin: This didn't work for me, but gave me some other ideas to try. See my answer to my question.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the `androidx.core:core-ktx` to version `1.1.0-rc01` also solved the problem.